# Do custom generic types work with precompile?

Tags: .net, protobuf-net

The following type seems to serialize ok with Protobuf-net when using JIT.
I have it working on Windows, Mac and Android.

```
// Stores a pair of values
[ProtoContract]
public class OneTwo<T>
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public T One = default(T);

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public T Two= default(T);

    public OneTwo() { }

    public OneTwo(T One, T Two)
    {
        this.One = One;
        this.Two = Two;
    }   
}
```

However now I'm trying to get it to run on iOS, and hence using the "precompiler".
Because it was erroring, I tried running the precompiler from source code and discovered that

```
IProtoSerializer ser = TryGetCoreSerializer(model, dataFormat, finalType, out wireType, asReference, dynamicType, OverwriteList, true);
```

is returning null on line 322 of ValueMember.cs for this type when finalType.DeclaringType is "OneTwo'1[T]", finalType.MemberType is "NestedType", and finalType.underlyingType is "{T}".

I'm wondering if I should expect this to work when using JIT to create the model at runtime but fail when trying to precompile for AOT?

And if this is indeed to be expected, what would be my best work around?

Comment: Btw, if the suggestion works, but the extra class offends - I would be willing to consider improving the API here.

Answer (score 1):

As far as protobuf-net is concerned, `OneTwo<Foo>` is largely unrelated to `OneTwo<Bar>`, and `OneTwo<>` (the open generic type) is meaningless. It is preparing a strategy separately for each `OneTwo<{something}>` the first time it sees each type.

Your best net is to trick precompile into knowing the `T` you intend on using at runtime. Perhaps:

```
[ProtoContract, Obsolete("this is not the class you are looking for", true)]
[Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public class BagOfEvil {
    [ProtoMember(1)] public OneTwo<Foo> Foo {get;set;}
    [ProtoMember(2)] public OneTwo<Bar> Bar {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

Now it knows about the concrete types you will be using.

Comment: I wondered if I understood what you were saying I should do, and now I am pretty sure I don't understand...

I created a class (called BagOfEvil) as you describe, I added a property 

[ProtoMember(40)]
OneTwo<List<Guid>> dummy1 { get; set; } 

to it and I removed the ProtoContract and ProtoMember from the generic type definition.

But I am still getting "No serializer defined for type" w.r.t. OneTwo<List<Guid>>

In the office, here, I am known as "The Stupid One" (but i put in extra hours to make up)... 

Could you spell it out a bit more?

Comment: @user2136212 well... why did you remove the ProtoContract and ProtoMember from the generic type definition? Those were needed...

Comment: @user2136212 to be explicit: the only purpose `BagOfEvil` serves here is to make it look at the encapsulated types, and consider them as part of the model

Comment: I am sure I am just doing something wrong, but I have created a demo project (so you can hopefully tell me what I am doing wrong) and uploaded it to the issues list:
https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=396

Comment: @user k - will look later (busy at the moment)

Comment: @user2136212 hmmm... looks like I'm the one doing something wrong; I will have to investigate and fix; that should have worked; sorry

Comment: Marc, could I use the old method described here http://www.frictionpointstudios.com/blog/2011/3/31/using-protobuf-net-serialization-in-unity-iphone.html
as an alternative? ... Or isn't that going to work anymore?
I have been able to create precompiled serialization dlls using this older method, the project builds, but when I come to run it on the ipad or simulator, it complains about assemblies failing to load.

Comment: Ah... hold on I think I realized the answer to my own question. It is because the I have the compiling code in the same assembly as the DTO code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this by editing the Program.cs of precompile program, to not add any open generic types to the model, since I have other types that use the closed generic type it will automatically generate all of the needed closed generic type serialization code

In PreCompileContext.Execute()

```
foreach (var type in toAdd)
{
    if (type.IsGenericTypeDefinition) // dont add open generic types to model
        continue;

    Console.WriteLine("Adding " + type.FullName + "...");

    var tmp = model.Add(type, true);

    if (metaType == null) metaType = tmp; // use this as the template for the framework version
}
```